# Angular Controller registeration

Tags: angularjs, controller

A very basic but intuitive question. Is writing 'ng-controller' under 'ng-app' mutually exclusive to registering the controller to the app in JS.

I  mean if i don't write resgisteration in the JS, but still in the HTML it is scoped under the ng-app. So does it create any problem. Any good explanation on this than the obvious one.
Thanks.

Code Sample-
http://plnkr.co/edit/zO0dBR5UK2OTpERSZQei?p=preview

```
 filterDemo.controller('displayController', ['$scope', function($scope) { }]);
```

If i don't register the controller in the script, how does it matter when already in the HTML the controller is inside the app.

Comment: can you post some code to make it more clear what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**

Registering the controller to the app (or to any other module within the app) is a completely different operation that writing 'ng-controller' in the HTML. So they are **NOT mutually exclusive**. On the contrary, they are both required for your controller to function correctly***.

You do not want the "obvious explanation", yet, your question is about basic Angular concepts which tend to be "obvious". I'll try to dig more or have a slightly different angle to it. But it isn't that much different than what the Angular docs talks about really.

### Registering Controller to the app

If you do not register the controller, it will be completely ignored by the Angular app. Almost like you did not even include the .js file in the HTML! In Angular, (almost) virtually nothing is global and thus you have to register about everything to make it active. Registering can be on the main app module directly or any other module that is dependent on the app. (modules can also depend on other modules, etc).

### Writing ng-controller in the HTML

Referencing a controller in the HTML is a bit like creating an "instance" of the controller. You can create zero (0), 1 or even many of them in the same page. On top of that, controller can come and go at any time.

The following information is a bit Off Topic, but can be useful when thinking about controllers and what they "mean":

***There are alternative ways to instantiate a controller:  Instead of writing it in the HTML, you can also have controllers referenced from directives or the $routeProvider's routes which will do the same.

#### Routes can reference controllers too

A detail about the $routeProvider case: when you have a view template that references a ng-controller from the root element in the template HTML, it has the exact same effect as being referenced from the route definition, in that sense this is somewhat *mutually exclusive* - although specifying in both place will not yield an error, I believe they are going to be the same instance. (I hope I have not confused you even more here).

### Controller, Scope and DOM are linked

Controllers are always associated with a 'scope'. They cannot exists without a 'scope'. In turn, a 'scope' cannot live outside the DOM. A 'scope' is always associated with one and only one element in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks Bernard for the explanation, I think the punch line was- Referencing a controller in the HTML is a bit like creating an "instance" of the controller.

But if i have a function defined with the name of the controller in my JS, is it possible that the HTML instance (ng-controller="function_Name") will reference that. And this without the registering controller code.

Comment: Ah I see, well, I believe creating a global Javascript function was historically the "original" way of creating a controller. It is roughly equivalent to registering it to the app. So you can pick one way or the other (but not both). It's a choice.
I believe using a global JS function to define a controller is a deprecated practice. It may not be _officially_ deprecated as I have not come across an official line stating this, but this is my feeling at least. It certainly limits controllers on many regards.

Comment: I think you have nailed it down.

Answer (score 0):

I follow the convention of registering all scripts after the body tag in my html file to make sure all my html is loaded before I start executing scripts.
What you are doing will work too. My only feedback is that it might be confusing to see script tags scattered around your code like this.

Anther concern is ability to unit test your code. If you introduce a dependency on the DOM to load your scripts it becomes harder to unit test.

Comment: Good point. Although I would assume Subhranshu used a script block for brevity purposes for asking a question.

Comment: Thanks Bernard for clarifying that. TGH i understand your point, but here the argument is different.